# Unable to figure out nInputPlane in SpatialConvolution in torch?

Tags: neural-network, torch

Documentaion for Spatial Convolution define it as

```
module = nn.SpatialConvolution(nInputPlane, nOutputPlane, kW, kH, [dW], [dH], [padW], [padH])
```

nInputPlane: The number of expected input planes in the image given into forward().

nOutputPlane: The number of output planes the convolution layer will produce.

I don't have any experience with torch but i guess i have used a similar function in keras

```
Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(3, 256, 256))
```

which takes as input the shape of the image that is 256*256 in rgb.

I have read usage of Spatial Convolution in torch as below but unable to figure out what does the nInputPlane and nOutputPlane paramter correspond to?

```
local convLayer = nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(384, 384, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

In the code above what does these 384,384 represent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case I'm not speaking common language you can refer to [this](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layers).

`nIputPlane` is the number of layers coming in to the convolution, `nOutputPlane` is number of layers coming out of the convolution. If you have an rgb image `nInputPlane  = 3` (assuming your tensor is setup correctly). `nOutputPlane` can be any number of layers that you want to come out of the spatial convolution but of course make sure the next layer input is equal to `nOutputPlane`.

If that isn't clear I'd recommend the [60-minute blitz](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb).